# css div margin issue

Tags: html, css

http://www.Kbay.in ...its wat im workin on.  The blue colored nav strip appears on behind the nav panel whereas i want it to be below the nav as if the nav buttons are sittin on it.  I gave it:

```
margin-top:30px;
```

That works fine but only in Firefox, other browsers still show the strip behind the nav,
until i give:

```
margin-top:50px;
```

then firefox gets screwed up and shows it way below the nav. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: question is clear, he's talking about cross-browser CSS adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error is with IE wich is messing with margin-fusions.

[CSS Margins Overlap Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906640/css-margins-overlap-problem)

i recommand the use of this to help you deal with this issue if it's your first time
it wil reset your margins and padding to 0 and then you can rebuild them 1 at the time while testing if it's working.
    `*{margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: yes, it will appen in every browsers, you need to code universally.