# giving child div a margin relative to the parent div

Tags: html, css, margin

This is my html:

```
<div class='parentDiv'>
    <div class='childDiv'></div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.parentDiv {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: red;
}

.childDiv {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
```

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1whywvpa/

How come childDiv does not get the margin-top of 22px? It only gets a margin top if the pixels is greater then the 200px which is already given to the parentDiv. Any way to make the childDiv get a parent div of 22px relative to the parentDiv without doing some type of 'give the parent div a 1px padding' hack?

Comment: `position: absolute;` to `.childDiv` will work but I'm not sure you'll use it.

Comment: @MaryMelody yea I don't want to use position:absolute;

Comment: Set `display: inline-block;` to `.childDiv` or `.parentDiv` - http://jsfiddle.net/1whywvpa/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1whywvpa/4/

Comment: Hello ,
it's normal in CSS documentary if MARGIN across other margin the big margin count the other margin ignore , you should separate your margins with Border or Padding .

for example you can add to your css :

.parentDiv { 
    padding : 1px ;
}

or add border 

.parentDiv { 
    border : 1px solid red ;
}

Comment: @MaryMelody thanks, I think I like your solution the most as I do not want to position div's absolutely nor do I want to make the childDiv float left. Put it down as the answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help: [CSS Margins Overlap Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906640/css-margins-overlap-problem)

Add position property to both elements. Parent is `relative` and child is `absolute`...

```
.parentDiv {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: red;
}

.childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/1whywvpa/5/

Comment: I wanted to do it without setting childDiv to position: absolute or making it float. I found 'display: inline-block' to be the best solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `.childDiv` isn't floated left.

If you `float: left;` the `.childDiv`, as I have in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MangopearUK/1whywvpa/1/), it will apply the margin as required.

Comment: any way to do it if I don't want childDiv to float left?

Comment: Set `display: inline-block;` to `.childDiv` or `.parentDiv` - http://jsfiddle.net/1whywvpa/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/1whywvpa/6/

Comment: @MaryMelody Or giving the parent a `overflow: hidden` or `padding-top: 1px;` or `border-top: 1px solid transparent;`. This is caused by [Collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Comment: @HashemQolami Yeah! Thanks! and _I remember that you told me about collapsing margins before. :)_

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use margin in this case. You should add padding to the parent div. You also need to close your parent div. So remove the `margin-top:22px` on the child div. Add `padding-top:22px;` on the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Make the child div a percentage of the containing parent div:

```
.parentDiv {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    }

.childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 7%;
    height: 6%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    }
```