# Bootstrap accordion menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Accordion menu]

I have designed a accordion menu like in the image. If you click a menu the opened menu will get closed.This is the functionality of accordion. But in this design i've clicks menu one by one but the previous one was not closing.. How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        };
    }
    
});
```

```css
.boot-accordian {
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #362f29;
  color: #e96f0a;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #3e352c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e352c;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 0.8% 1% 0.8% 3%;
}
.boot-accordian .para {
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion.active,
.boot-accordian button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #362f29;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion:after {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f067";
  float: right;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.boot-accordian div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #433a31;
}
.boot-accordian div.panel.show {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boot-accordian">
<button class="accordion">listings</button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
 </div>
<button class="accordion">contract information</button>
 <div class="panel">
<p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of  contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
 </div>
<button class="accordion">letter templates</button>
 <div class="panel">
 <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of  contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook or Google Calendaraccounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">tasks and task templates</button>
 <div class="panel">
<p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
 </div>
<button class="accordion">secure file storage</button>
<div class="panel">
<p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
</div>
  <button class="accordion">reports</button>
 <div class="panel">
 <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is not a Bootstrap accordion... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: I'm just developed customized menu like accordion... As you said not a bs accordion.. But partially.. Menu collapsing is the issue.. Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at this jQuery approach:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
     var oldAcc = $(".accordion.active");
     oldAcc.toggleClass("active");
     oldAcc.next().toggleClass("show");
}
```

With above code we are getting reference to already opened accordion and closing it before opening the other one.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      var oldAcc = $(".accordion.active");
      oldAcc.toggleClass("active");
      oldAcc.next().toggleClass("show");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("show");


  });

});
```

```css
.boot-accordian {
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #362f29;
  color: #e96f0a;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #3e352c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3e352c;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 0.8% 1% 0.8% 3%;
}
.boot-accordian .para {
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion.active,
.boot-accordian button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #362f29;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion:after {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f067";
  color: @color_24;
  float: right;
}
.boot-accordian button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.boot-accordian div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #433a31;
}
.boot-accordian div.panel.show {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boot-accordian">
  <button class="accordion">listings</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook
      or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">contract information</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook
      or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">letter templates</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook
      or Google Calendaraccounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">tasks and task templates</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook
      or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">secure file storage</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook
      or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">reports</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p class="para">Store all the necessary contract information such as important dates, closer & agent contact information, special contract teams, etc. You can even upload digital copies of contracts, title policies - and send important date reminders to your Outlook
      or Google Calendar accounts, iphone or Blackberry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** first this is not bootstrap accordion

here is solution just add these 2 lines when you click

```
$(".accordion").removeClass("active");
$(".panel").removeClass("show");
```

better to write some thing like this way ([Pure JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/59qcbd1m/1/))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion").click(function(){
    $(".accordion").removeClass("active");
    $(".panel").removeClass("show");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next(".panel").addClass("show");
  })
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59qcbd1m/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply wanting one to slide down while the others slide back up, use the following code:

```
$('.accordion').click(function() {
    var targetElement = $(this).next('.panel');
    targetElement.slideToggle();
    targetElement.siblings('.panel').slideUp();
});
```

example here [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XKGwbk)

ENJOY... :)

Comment: Why it's getting empty space below on every panel?

Comment: @PrasathV hava look this question for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906640/css-margins-overlap-problem

i have fixed this issue in my answer by adding overflow: auto; in .boot-accordian div.panel

Comment: Yes it's taking `margin-bottom` on `.panel` .. I have checked and fixed that. :)

Comment: yes its the margin issue as the example contains bootstrap CSS , which overrides some CSS style in your CSS. Now its fixed i removed the bootstrap   updated link is here [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XKGwbk)

Answer (score 2):

Just do it right with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $('.accordion').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this),
      activeEl = $('.active'),
      openedEl = $('.show');

      // remove the active state
      activeEl.removeClass('active');
      openedEl.removeClass('show');
      // add active state for unactive elements only
      if(!target.is(activeEl)) {
        target.addClass('active');
        target.next().addClass('show');
      }
  });
});
```